# Spring Security - Why have separate classes for user and role?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security to my app, and because of that I have been reading a lot of articles on the net. One thing I have noticed is that there are a lot of examples where user role class is separated from user class. Why is this so, is this general best practice rule? Or is there a possibility to add role field to user class and use enum data type, so instead of heaving two tables in database for authentication, we only have one? Can someone help me understand this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user can have more than one role. A member of the support team can have the rules "user" and "support" so they can use the system in the same way a normal user can to verify problem reports, for example.

Another example is that you often want fine grained roles. Instead of "admin" and "user", you can have different user roles for guests and for people who may just work on a certain part of the system.

Think eBay: You have customers and sellers. Sellers can do more than mere buyers. But sellers also need to buy things if they want. Then some sellers may want to split their people into "can add offers" and "can give discount." While all employees will have the former, only a select few will have the latter.

Answer (score 2):

The classic design is User-Group-Role.  A User can belong to many Groups; a Role can be granted to one or more Groups; there can be many Groups.  It's a ternary relationship.

I wouldn't consider reducing the size of a schema by a single table worth the violence it does to a good abstraction.